# Can the windows and application keys be used for custom bindings in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know if its possible to somehow add custom keyboard bindings in visual studio 2010 using the windows key or application key.

I would like to map Windows Key + HJKL to replace the use my arrow keys. However I don't want to lose the current bindings on these keys (+ CTL, SHIFT or ALT).

I had a look at the vssettings file and key bindings look like this:

```
<Shortcut Command="Edit.SelectCurrentWord" Scope="Text Editor">Ctrl+W</Shortcut>
```

So what I want to do is something like this:

```
<Shortcut Command="Edit.SelectCurrentWord" Scope="Text Editor">Windows+W</Shortcut>
```

Which ofcourse does not work.  Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested, I ended up using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.net/~Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/).  My script looks like this:

```
#h::Send {Left}
#^h::Send ^{Left}
#!h::Send !{Left}
#+h::Send +{Left}
#^!+h::Send ^!+{Left}
#^!h::Send ^!{Left}
#^+h::Send ^+{Left}
#!+h::Send !+{Left}

#k::Send {Right}
#^k::Send ^{Right}
#!k::Send !{Right}
#+k::Send +{Right}
#^!+k::Send ^!+{Right}
#^!k::Send ^!{Right}
#^+k::Send ^+{Right}
#!+k::Send !+{Right}

#u::Send {Up}
#^u::Send ^{Up}
#!u::Send !{Up}
#+u::Send +{Up}
#^!+u::Send ^!+{Up}
#^!u::Send ^!{Up}
#^+u::Send ^+{Up}
#!+u::Send !+{Up}

#j::Send {Down}
#^j::Send ^{Down}
#!j::Send !{Down}
#+j::Send +{Down}
#^!+j::Send ^!+{Down}
#^!j::Send ^!{Down}
#^+j::Send ^+{Down}
#!+j::Send !+{Down}

#y::Send {PgUp}
#^y::Send ^{PgUp}
#!y::Send !{PgUp}
#+y::Send +{PgUp}
#^!+y::Send ^!+{PgUp}
#^!y::Send ^!{PgUp}
#^+y::Send ^+{PgUp}
#!+y::Send !+{PgUp}

#i::Send {PgDn}
#^i::Send ^{PgDn}
#!i::Send !{PgDn}
#+i::Send +{PgDn}
#^!+i::Send ^!+{PgDn}
#^!i::Send ^!{PgDn}
#^+i::Send ^+{PgDn}
#!+i::Send !+{PgDn}

#8::Send {End}
#^8::Send ^{End}
#!8::Send !{End}
#+8::Send +{End}
#^!+8::Send ^!+{End}
#^!8::Send ^!{End}
#^+8::Send ^+{End}
#!+8::Send !+{End}

#7::Send {Home}
#^7::Send ^{Home}
#!7::Send !{Home}
#+7::Send +{Home}
#^!+7::Send ^!+{Home}
#^!7::Send ^!{Home}
#^+7::Send ^+{Home}
#!+7::Send !+{Home}
```

Just save that to a file in your 'Startup' folder (extension .ahk).

Thanks all